# Sql save the result of query to variable running on postgres docker

Tags: postgresql

I have a SELECT query and I want to execute the result of this query as well. I think I need a variable to save it first and then execute. Some other answers to such question included commands from system bash, but I have a postgres running on my docker and I already entered my database in postgres. So how the command may look like?

Comment: Can you call Postgres from your application programming language?

Comment: No, I need to execute it through postgres bash